# Android Sqlite Foreign Key Unknwon Column

Tags: android, sqlite, exception, key

I added foreign keys to my database. I reinstalled the app from my device and increased the database version. Here is my code:

Constant: `private static final String COLUMN_K_ID = "kid";`

Create Tables:

```
  private static final String CREATE_TABLE_ZIELE_KOERPER =  "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ZIELE_KOERPER + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID           + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_OPTION       + " INTEGER, "   +
            COLUMN_TENDENZ      + " INTEGER );";

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_ZIELE_CARDIO =  "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ZIELE_CARDIO + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID           + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_EXTRA        + " TEXT );";

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_ZIELE_TRAINING =  "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ZIELE_TRAINING + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID           + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_EXTRA        + " TEXT, "      +
            COLUMN_MUSKEL       + " TEXT, "      +
            COLUMN_WIEDERHOLUNGEN + " INTEGER )";

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_ZIELE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ZIELE + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            "FOREIGN KEY(" + COLUMN_K_ID + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_ZIELE_KOERPER      + "(" + COLUMN_ID + ")  ON DELETE CASCADE, " +
            "FOREIGN KEY(" + COLUMN_C_ID + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_ZIELE_CARDIO       + "(" + COLUMN_ID + ")  ON DELETE CASCADE, " +
            "FOREIGN KEY(" + COLUMN_T_ID + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_ZIELE_TRAINING     + "(" + COLUMN_ID + ")  ON DELETE CASCADE, " +
            COLUMN_NAME         + " TEXT, "      +
            COLUMN_ERSTELLDATUM + " LONG, "      +
            COLUMN_DEADLINE     + " LONG, "      +
            COLUMN_DONE         + " INTEGER, "   +
            COLUMN_VALUE        + " FLOAT, "     +
            COLUMN_FORTSCHRITT  + " FLOAT "      +
            ");";

@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ZIELE_KOERPER);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ZIELE_CARDIO);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ZIELE_TRAINING);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ZIELE);
    }
```

Log:

*unknown column "kid" in foreign key definition (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE ziele(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, FOREIGN KEY(kid) REFERENCES koerperziele(id)  ON DELETE CASCADE, FOREIGN KEY(cid) REFERENCES cardioziele(id)  ON DELETE CASCADE, FOREIGN KEY(t_id) REFERENCES trainingsziele(id)  ON DELETE CASCADE, name TEXT, erstelldatum LONG, deadline LONG, done INTEGER, value FLOAT, fortschritt FLOAT );*

Activate foreign keys:

```
 @Override
    public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onOpen(db);
        db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON");
    }
```

EDIT: Still not working

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_ZIELE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ZIELE + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_NAME         + " TEXT, "      +
            COLUMN_ERSTELLDATUM + " LONG, "      +
            COLUMN_DEADLINE     + " LONG, "      +
            COLUMN_DONE         + " INTEGER, "   +
            COLUMN_VALUE        + " FLOAT, "     +
            COLUMN_FORTSCHRITT  + " FLOAT, "     +
            "FOREIGN KEY(" + COLUMN_K_ID + " INTEGER) REFERENCES " + TABLE_ZIELE_KOERPER      + "(" + COLUMN_ID + ")  ON DELETE CASCADE, " +
            "FOREIGN KEY(" + COLUMN_C_ID + " INTEGER) REFERENCES " + TABLE_ZIELE_CARDIO       + "(" + COLUMN_ID + ")  ON DELETE CASCADE, " +
            "FOREIGN KEY(" + COLUMN_T_ID + " INTEGER) REFERENCES " + TABLE_ZIELE_TRAINING     + "(" + COLUMN_ID + ")  ON DELETE CASCADE  " + ");";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `CREATE TABLE` for `TABLE_ZIELE` has two kinds of problems:

1. You need to actually specify the columns you use as foreign keys, e.g. `cid INTEGER`.
2. Constraints such as `FOREIGN KEY`s go after column specifications part. Move them at the end.

Comment: The first one is wrong, because its a foreign key. And the second one didnt help

Comment: You need them both. Table constraints don't declare columns and you cannot mix table constraints between column specifications.

Comment: Yes you're still missing the three column specifications for the foreign keys in that table.

Comment: Ok I found my mistake. I was really stupid. You're totally right. I'm sry!

Answer (score 2):

You have to implement `FOREIGN KEY` as a table or column constraint. In the first case which you chose, you need to reference a column you defined before.

In the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) you find some examples for how to do it correctly.

In your case you'd need to use the column constraints instead, which it looks like you intended to do.

You can just replace the lines like

```
"FOREIGN KEY(" + COLUMN_K_ID + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_ZIELE_KOERPER + "(" + COLUMN_ID + ")  ON DELETE CASCADE, " +
```

with

```
COLUMN_K_ID + " REFERENCES " + TABLE_ZIELE_KOERPER + "(" + COLUMN_ID + ")  ON DELETE CASCADE, " +
```

Comment: I dont get it. Why should i remove that FOREIGN KEY(...)?

Comment: Because that's how you define a column which references a foreign table. `FOREIGN KEY` is only used for table constraints